# Do you know any website which allow query execution?

Tags: web

I wanted to know if there is any system which allow me to create my own tables and execute query on those tables? I want these because I don't have any database installed on my office computer and I want to practice queries in my free time.

Comment: Lucky guy gets free time in office :-) whats the harm in installing a database?

Comment: Perhaps he has this fellow http://bofh.ntk.net/BOFH/index.php running the computers in his department.

Comment: @sushil SSSShhhhhhhhh Don't tell this to my boss :-) It's a secrete between us...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The following answer largely assumes you are using Windows.]

For a very quick-n-dirty sandbox, try SQLite. It comes with [sqlite3.exe](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html) (see the *Precompiled Binaries For Windows* section), which lets you create tables and run queries over them from the command-line.

SQLite's dialect of SQL is a bit strange due to its dynamic typing model, so you might get more mileage from installing a more conventional database like [PostgreSQL](http://www.enterprisedb.com/products/pgdownload.do#windows), though it is more involved than SQLite's "installation", which amounts to extracting the .exe file and sticking it somewhere on your path.

Comment: Yes, I am using Windows. But, I don't want to install any dbms.

Comment: @Himadri: sqlite3.exe is a completely self-contained program that provides a convenient database command-line. It is literally a single file that you can just copy onto your computer and run, without any installation process. See [here](http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html) for more information and a quick tutorial. It will take you five minutes to download it, run it, and decide for yourself whether it does what you want.

Answer (score 1):

There is one online query execution tool provided by [w3cshcools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_tryit.asp)

I got this answer after asking a question in [this](http://www.indiastudychannel.com/experts/15101-Want-online-query-execution.aspx) forum.